# Moving Maven artifact to new group

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I changed maven group ids for my project some time ago, from [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stellar.scala.sdk/scala-stellar-sdk) to [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.synesso/scala-stellar-sdk). In mvnrepository, the old group id persists on page one of the search results - which is annoying because none of those versions work anymore, and the real project with working versions is on [page 2](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=stellar&p=2).

I noticed that other artifacts have a *moved* notice on their page. e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guava

[image: example moved notice]

What do I need to do to mark my artifact as having been *moved*?

Comment: Maybe you need to do a relocation? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html

Comment: The relocation is the right way to go..